# How can I prove this language is regular?

Tags: finite-automata, automata, computation-theory, dfa, formal-languages

I'm trying to prove if this language:

> L = { w={0,1}* | #<sub>0</sub>(w) % 3 = 0 } (number of 0's is divisble by 3)

is regular using the pumping lemma, but I can't find a way to do it. All other examples I got, have a simple form or let's say a more defined form such as w = a<sup>x</sup>b<sup>y</sup>c<sup>z</sup> etc.

Answer (score 4):

<s>Any string in this language with at least three characters in it has this property: either the string has a "`1`" in it, or there are three "`0`"s in a row.</s>

<s>If the string contains a `1`, then you can split it as in the pumping lemma and set *y* equal to some `1` in the string. Then obviously the strings *xyz*, *xyyz*, *xyyyz*, etc. are all in the language because all those strings have the same number of zeros.</s>

<s>If the string does not contain a `1`, it contains three `0`s in a row. Setting *y* to those three `0`s, it should be obvious that *xyz*, *xyyz*, *xyyyz*, etc. are all in the language because you're adding three `0` characters each time, so you always have a number of `0`s divisible by 3.</s>

@justhalf in the comments is perfectly correct; the pumping lemma can be used to prove that a regular language can be pumped or that a language that cannot be pumped is not regular, but you cannot use the pumping lemma to prove that a language is regular in the first place. Mea Culpa.

Instead, here's a proof that the given language is regular based on the [Myhill-Nerode Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem):

Consider the set of all strings of `0`s and `1`s. Divide these strings into three sets:

> *E<sub>0</sub>*, all strings such that the number of `0`s is a multiple of three,
>
> *E<sub>1</sub>*, all strings such that the number of `0`s is one more than a multiple of three,
>
> *E<sub>2</sub>*, all strings such that the number of `0`s is two more than a multiple of three.

Obviously, every string of `0`s and `1`s is in one of these three sets.

Furthermore, if *x* and *z* are both strings of `0`s and `1`s, then consider what it means if the concatenation *xz* is in *L*:

1. If *x* is in *E<sub>0</sub>*, then *xz* is in *L* if and only if *z* is in *E<sub>0</sub>*
2. If *x* is in *E<sub>1</sub>*, then *xz* is in *L* if and only if *z* is in *E<sub>2</sub>*
3. If *x* is in *E<sub>2</sub>*, then *xz* is in *L* if and only if *z* is in *E<sub>1</sub>*

Therefore, in the language of the theorem, there is no distinguishing extension for any two strings in the same one of our three *E<sub>i</sub>* sets, and therefore there are at most three equivalence classes. A finite number of equivalence classes means the language is regular.

(in fact, there are exactly three equivalence classes, but that isn't needed)

Comment: I don't think you can prove a language is regular using pumping lemma. Do you have references for that? I have only seen pumping lemma used for proving that a language is not regular.

Comment: Cool proof! Downvote undone =) Essentially you have just (almost) defined the finite automaton, I guess.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can use pumping lemma to prove that a language is regular. To prove a language is regular, you just need to give a regular expression or a DFA. In this case the regular expression is quite easy:

```
1*(01*01*01*)*
```

(proof: the regular expression clearly does not accept any string which has the number of 0's not divisible by 3, so we just need to prove that all possible strings which has the number of 0's divisible by 3 is accepted by this regular expression, which can be done by confirming that for strings that contain 3n 0's, the regular expression matches it since 1<sup>n<sub>0</sub></sup>01<sup>n<sub>1</sub></sup>01<sup>n<sub>2</sub></sup>01<sup>n<sub>3</sub></sup>...01<sup>n<sub>3n-2</sub></sup>01<sup>n<sub>3n-1</sub></sup>01<sup>n<sub>3n</sub></sup> has the same number of 0's and the n<sub>k</sub>'s can be substituted so that it matches the string, and that this format is clearly accepted by the regular expression)

Pumping lemma cannot be used to prove that a language is regular because we cannot set the `y` as in Daniel Martin's answer. Here is a counter-example, in a similar format as his answer (please correct me if I'm doing something fundamentally different from his answer):

> We prove that the language L = {w=0<sup>n</sup>1<sup>p</sup> | n ∈ N, n>0, p is prime} is regular using pumping lemma as follows: note that there is at least one occurrence of 0, so we take y as 0, and we have xy<sup>k</sup>z = 0<sup>n+k-1</sup>1<sup>p</sup>, which still satisfy the language definition. Therefore L is regular.

But this is false, since we know that a sequence with prime-numbered length is not regular. The problem here is we cannot just set y to any character.

Comment: You are right, I didn't ask my question correctly. You use the lemma to prove a language is not regular by using proof by contradiction. As far as I've understand, you assume L is a regular language, we take a constant m, we choose a word w in L, which length is bigger than m, we break w in 3 words xyz, we choose an integer i, we prove that xy^iz is not an element of L, which is a contradiction to the pumping lemma, therefore the assumption was false, resulting in the fact that the language is not regular.

Comment: Yes, that's how you would use pumping lemma to prove a language is not regular.

Comment: Your regex doesn't allow a nonempty string of all `1`s. I think you meant `1*(01*01*01*)*`. Of course, you the then need to prove that the regular expression matches the language statement.

Comment: @DanielMartin: Ah, yes, that was a mistake on my part. Yes, if you want to prove the language is regular, then we need to prove that the strings accepted by the regular expression is the same as the strings described in the language description.

Answer (score 2):

- A language is **regular** if and only if some nondeterministic finite automaton recognizes it.
- Automaton is a finite state machine.

We have to build an automaton that regonizes L.

For each state, thinking like:

- "Where am I?"
- "Where can I go to, with some given entry?"

So, for L = { w={0,1}* | #0(w) % 3 = 0 }

The possibilites (states) are:
The remainder (rest of division) is 0, 1 or 2. Which means we need three states.
Let *q0*,*q1* and *q2* be the states that represent the remainderes 0,1 and 2, respectively.

*q0* is the start and final state.

Now, for "0" entries, do the math #0(w)%3 and go to the aproppriated state.

Transion functions:

f(q0, 0) = q1

f(q1, 0) = q2

f(q2, 0) = q0

For "1" entries, it just loops wherever it is, 'cause it doesn't change the machine state.

f(qx, 1) = qx

The pumping lemma proves if some language is **not regular**.

Here is a good book for theory of computation: *Introduction to the Theory of Computation 3rd Edition
by Michael Sipser.*